# How can I get MIN, MAX, AVG working with an innerjoin?

Tags: mysql

I need to get the Average, Minimum and Maximum for each industry type from a data set. When I use the MIN, MAX, AVG functions it just returns the same value as the Amount column.

**My attempt**

```
SELECT c.Custid, c.Cname, c.City, c.IndustryType, o.OrderNo, o.OrderDate, o.SalesPersonID, o.Amount, 
AVG(o.Amount) AS 'Average Amount',
MIN(o.Amount) AS 'Minimum Amount',
MAX(o.Amount) AS 'Maximum Amount'
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN orders o
ON c.custid = o.custid
GROUP BY c.IndustryType,o.orderdate;
```

Comment: Remove everything from the first line except of `c.IndustryType`. Also remove `o.orderdate` from the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Post your table definitions and some sample data set related to your problem

Comment: @Paul Spiegel, Okay that worked but I don't understand why it breaks my result, and could I display all the fields id,name,city etc in my result?

Comment: Sorry, i've tried to explain that, but I feel like I would write the documentation (which would be to broad even for an answer). So please read [the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) first.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Standards require that a `GROUP BY` clause contains **ALL** the columns that do **NOT** use an `aggregate function` (i.e. min(),max(),avg() etc.).

> SQL92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list,
>   HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that
>   are not named in the GROUP BY clause.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

MySQL however implemented an additional capability for `GROUP BY` which is NON-standard , and in old versions of MySQL it defaulted to that NON-standard approach. (There is a server setting that you can alter to flip from standard to non-standard syntax for grouping.) Since MySQL 5.7.5 the default setting changed to the SQL Standard approach.

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If
>   the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default),
>   MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in
>   the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them.

See: [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Almost certainly the reason your original query did not work is for the above considerations. Many will tell you that using the non-standard approach is poor practice, and indeed if you research the topic further you will learn that the non-standard approach returns "indeterminate results" for all those columns not included in the group by clause (except in rare cases). You are much better off using the standard approach all the time. e.g.

```
SELECT
      c.IndustryType
    , o.OrderDate
    , AVG(o.Amount) AS "Average Amount"
    , MIN(o.Amount) AS "Minimum Amount"
    , MAX(o.Amount) AS "Maximum Amount"
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.custid = o.custid
GROUP BY
      c.IndustryType
    , o.OrderDate
;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT
      c.Custid
    , c.Cname
    , c.City
    , c.IndustryType
    , o.OrderNo
    , o.OrderDate
    , o.SalesPersonID
    , o.Amount
    , AVG(o.Amount) AS "Average Amount"
    , MIN(o.Amount) AS "Minimum Amount"
    , MAX(o.Amount) AS "Maximum Amount"
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.custid = o.custid
GROUP BY
      c.Custid
    , c.Cname
    , c.City
    , c.IndustryType
    , o.OrderNo
    , o.OrderDate
    , o.SalesPersonID
    , o.Amount
;
```

It is worth mentioning that your original query appears to want an aggregate calculated for each unique combination of (IndustryType & OrderDate) but to repeat those aggregates over several more rows of detail. There are "window functions" that allow for this to occur which are under development and intended for release with MySQL 8.x, these functions exist in other databases already for example DB2, Oracle, SQL Server, Postgre, SQL Lite, MariaDB (and more).

The syntax for windowed aggregations looks like this:

```
SELECT
      c.Custid
    , c.Cname
    , c.City
    , c.IndustryType
    , o.OrderNo
    , o.OrderDate
    , o.SalesPersonID
    , o.Amount
    , AVG(o.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY c.IndustryType, o.OrderDate)
        AS "Average Amount" 
    , MIN(o.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY c.IndustryType, o.OrderDate)
        AS "Minimum Amount"
    , MAX(o.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY c.IndustryType, o.OrderDate)
        AS "Maximum Amount"
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.custid = o.custid
```